# Java : programmatically differentiate a thermal printer from a classic printer

Tags: java, printing, zebra-printers, thermal-printer

I'm building an app with Spring Boot. Its purpose is to print on thermal printers (Zebra, Datamax...). In order to do that, I want to establish a list of  printers connected to the user's computer (the target is Windows only).

Until now, I was using :

```
javax.print.PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor flavor, AttributeSet attributes)
```

But I can't find a way to differentiate the thermal printers from the "classic" printers with the DocFlavor or attributes.

Is there any way to get a list of the thermal printers only ? Or is there any attribute on a driver or a PrintService that could allow me to sort the printers ?

Thanks.